# Convert Filename to Timestamp using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to convert a filename to a timestamp for my laravel application.

`let test = "/2020-05-16_11-17-47_UTC_1.jpg"`

i tried to replace the `-` with split and join but i dont think its the best option..
It has to look like this: `2020-05-16 11:17:47`.

I tried it like this:

```
  let regex = test.toString().match('/[^/]*$')[0]
  let upload_date = regex.split("/").join("").split(".jpg").join("").split(".mp4").join("").split("_").join(" ")
```

Im struggling with replacing the `:`...

Comment: Can you please let me know how your file name will be appear before change the name? Is there any special format? and i hope your end result should be like `2020-05-16 11-17-47 UTC 1.jpg` or `.mp4`.

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi i get the filename like `"/2020-05-16_11-17-47_UTC_1.jpg"` and i only have to convert it to `2020-05-16 11:17:47`, i just want to know the best way to do it. :)

Comment: The original format, before the regex is something like `/home/insta/data/name/2019-07-30_12-43-39_UTC.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to over kill `split()` method in order to get the expected result.

```
let str = '/home/insta/data/name/2020-05-16_11-17-47_UTC_1.jpg';
let chunks = str.split('/');    
let formatted = chunks[chunks.length-1].replace(/[^0-9_-]/g, '').replace(/_/g,' ').slice(0,19);
console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Thanks, i now made it a but more complicated because i have to have `:` for the time. I did it like this: ```  let test = "/2020-05-16_11-17-47_UTC_1.jpg"

  let regex = path.toString().match('/[^/]*$')[0]
  let regex_done = regex.split("/").join("").split(".jpg").join("").split(".mp4").join("").split("_").join(" ").slice(0, 19)
  let date = regex_done.slice(0, 10)
  let time = regex_done.slice(12, 19).split("-").join(":")
  let upload_date = date + " " + time```